# What's the point of "val variable =" following by nothing in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, syntax

I accidentally hit enter after a value assignment and to my surprise it compiled perfectly fine!

What's the point of having this syntax? I tried to search for it online but only found articles about the Nothing-type, but nowhere close to this surprising syntax.

[image: Syntax from IntelliJ Idea]

Comment: Could you give an example of what your code looks like?

Comment: @AlexeySoshin I don't think it's relevant :) You can get this behaviour in any function when coding in IntelliJ IDEA (and probably also other IDE's)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, `return 123` is an expression which returns `Nothing`. Just like `throw RuntimeException()`. You can save the result of this expression in your variable but I cannot imagine how you can use it :)

Comment: Oh is it possible that return 123 returns `Nothing`? shouldn't it return an `Int`?

Comment: I know that it's pretty hard to understand. A function with the line `return 123` returns `123` but the line `return 123` by itself has type `Nothing`

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks! I'm still wondering why they allow such a line as highlighted in my screenshot to compile :D

Comment: Welcome! Why not? It's a correct variable declaration. Just a bit useless :)

Comment: Because it's useless I guess xD I'm using Kotlin for 3 years now and I always was stunned by the choice of features they allowed into their language. It seemed to be in perfect balance. This stroke me as odd... Still a really good language by the way!

Comment: @PeterWillemsen it follows from the rule `val name = expression`. `throw Exception()` is a valid expression, so it has to have a type: `Nothing`. It is a valid expression, so it has to be assignable to a variable. Everything being an expression is really powerful, so it's a good thing.